# JS code to change form submit is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, get

I have a form that has many fields in it. I am using JS code to modify the parameters submitted by that form via GET request.

Basically the form submits 3 params- search_address, search_city,search_state, search_zip along with other params-- My JS code just combines the address, city, state, and zip params into a single param and modifies the search query accordingly.

But when I run the page with the code below, the original query goes through as it is- as if the JS code has no effect. What am I doing wrong here?

This is the HTML code for the form HTML tag--

```
 <form method="get" class="searchform" id="searchform" action="target_URL_value">
```

This is the HTML code for the submit button--

```
 <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" onclick="JavaScript:submit_form()" style="width:20%" />
```

This is the Javascript code for submit_form function--

```
 <script>

 function submit_form()
 {
     $('searchform').submit( function() {
         var $form = $(this);
         //Arvind IMP put the below paraemeter's name as s or the value of name in Search field of original header.php in parent template...
         // This is a typical search string
         //?post_type=property&search_keyword=&submit=Search&price-min=&price-max=&city=&state=&zip=&beds=&baths=&sqft=&status=
         var data = 'post_type='+$('#post_type').val()+'&search_keyword='+$('#search_address').val()+", "+$('#search_city').val()+", "+$('#search_state').val()+", "+$('#search_zip').val()  
         + '&price-min='+$('#price-min').val()+ '&price-max='+$('#price-max').val() +'&city='+$('#search_city').val()
         + '&state='+$('#search_state').val()+ '&zip='+$('#search_zip').val() +'&beds='+$('#beds').val()
         + '&sqft='+$('#sqft').val()+ '&status='+$('#status').val();
         $.get( $form.attr('action'), data);
         return false;
     });
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not declare the submit event into a function.

Also remove inline code `onclick="JavaScript:submit_form()"`

And finally, do not forget the `#` of the form selector `$('#searchform')` to select the id (or `.` to select the class)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchform').submit(function () {
        var $form = $(this);
        //Arvind IMP put the below paraemeter's name as s or the value of name in Search field of original header.php in parent template...
        // This is a typical search string
        //?post_type=property&search_keyword=&submit=Search&price-min=&price-max=&city=&state=&zip=&beds=&baths=&sqft=&status=
        var data = 'post_type=' + $('#post_type').val() + '&search_keyword=' + $('#search_address').val() + ", " + $('#search_city').val() + ", " + $('#search_state').val() + ", " + $('#search_zip').val() + '&price-min=' + $('#price-min').val() + '&price-max=' + $('#price-max').val() + '&city=' + $('#search_city').val() + '&state=' + $('#search_state').val() + '&zip=' + $('#search_zip').val() + '&beds=' + $('#beds').val() + '&sqft=' + $('#sqft').val() + '&status=' + $('#status').val();
        $.get($form.attr('action'), data);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: "It is not working" is not a useful comment. Do you have some errors in console (press F12 to display the console)? Have you tried to set up a debug point in the submit event? Do you reach the submit event when you try to submit the form?

Comment: at first there was an error due to jquery not being loaded-- later I added simple console.log messages imm. after the function is loaded, and imm. when the form is sent- however now no message is shown(for both cases) and the URL to which form is sent remains unchanged...

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is incorrect. Plus you are registering the handler again and again, calling the submit button click. You dont need it. Just place your handler under document.ready to register first up.

#### Script

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('.searchform').submit(function () {

        var $form = $(this);
        //Arvind IMP put the below paraemeter's name as s or the value of name in Search field of original header.php in parent template...
        // This is a typical search string
        //?post_type=property&search_keyword=&submit=Search&price-min=&price-max=&city=&state=&zip=&beds=&baths=&sqft=&status=
        var data = 'post_type=' + $('#post_type').val() + '&search_keyword=' + $('#search_address').val() + ", " + $('#search_city').val() + ", " + $('#search_state').val() + ", " + $('#search_zip').val() + '&price-min=' + $('#price-min').val() + '&price-max=' + $('#price-max').val() + '&city=' + $('#search_city').val() + '&state=' + $('#search_state').val() + '&zip=' + $('#search_zip').val() + '&beds=' + $('#beds').val() + '&sqft=' + $('#sqft').val() + '&status=' + $('#status').val();
        $.get($form.attr('action'), data);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Remove `onclick="JavaScript:submit_form()"` from your button as you don't need it.

`<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit"  style="width:20%"  />`

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4KEjx/)

Comment: @Arvind What do you mean by `Not Working`? did you check if it is reaching the submit, any errors in console etc?

Comment: when I did not include JQuery I got the error "$ is not defined" again I added console.log messages imm. after function starts and when the form is loaded....However now no message is being logged and the page goes to original url (as if the JS function is not there at all)....

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a dot to designate the class, see:

```
$('searchform').submit( function() {
   ^----- HERE you lack a dot . to select class name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use `preventDefault()`:

```
function submit_form()
{
    $('.searchform').submit( function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         //rest of code
    });
}
```

- second add dot to selector `.searchform`;
- third remove `onclick="JavaScript:submit_form()"` from your form